# How to use RabbitMQ for storing form data in a 3-Tier architecture

Tags: php, wordpress, integration, sugarcrm, suitecrm

So in my test project I have 3 systems that I'm using:

1. Front end => WordPress form
2. Back end => SuiteCRM
3. Integration => Middleware (RabbitMQ)

I have a so called "person" who can register at an event on the WordPress site.

What I want to achieve after clicking on the button, is that the form-data gets posted into my CRM tool:

This means that the database table 'registered_users' of my CRM will be filled with the data of the form. (table is already created and the columns match the form).

My questions are:

1. Is the thing I'm striving for able to work using Middleware RabbitMQ? Can RabbitMQ be used for the transfer of PHP variables and storing them in a database?
2. If yes, What would my approach be integrating this middleware software?
3. Is the  idea a good one? Is RabbitMQ able to do this?
4. What are other good approaches to solve my problem but with the use of RabbitMQ like software?

Comment: It's a poor use of the term 'middleware'. In any case, RabbitMQ (as with all queues) takes some form of message. Then later on one or more consumers processes a message and removes it from the queue.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! What would be a good alternative for 'middleware'? I was struggling finding suitable term (an application which stands between 2 other applications). I thought it was correct. In my case, I'd guess the SuiteCRM is the consumer right?

Comment: The problem seems more like it's asking for ["N-tier"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture). Queues are useful when there is an asynchronous stream and can offer a number of advantages in some scenarios (routing, replay, load buffering). However this is not the correct solution for all problems.

Comment: Thanks I just edited the title

Comment: In any case, RabbitMQ would go like this: 1) the user presses button on a client (web browser) that submits the form; 2) the front-end web application (eg. PHP) publishes a message to a Rabbit Exchange with the required information; 3) a consumer application listens to a Queue from rabbit and 'does something' (whatever is is supposed to) in response to receiving the particular message/data.

Comment: Okay I like where this is heading! I have a question though, is it possible that the consumer application 'does something' with the message like a database input? This means the message (variables) need to be formatted in a certain way if i'm correct right?

Comment: Think of the message as JSON *text* (RabbitMQ allows any data, but..). The consuming application *only* knows what is in the message and any local context. The consumer has *no* knowledge of what variables existed in the publisher, except as such has been converted to information in the message. The JSON message could, for example, be built from the relevant registration form information.

Comment: Sure, it can do whatever it wants to do.

Comment: Thanks for all your information user2864740! I will brainstorm further and will try to transform your information into a working project!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what you want with RabbitMQ, but the architecture you need is slightly more than what you are suggesting.

1. User clicks submit on form, and posts to your web server
2. Web server captures the form submit and creates a JSON document
3. Web server publishes JSON document through RabbitMQ
4. Back-end service consumes JSON document and updates database

The basic RabbitMQ tutorials on PHP should get you going:

- http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-php.html

You're specifically looking for a Worker Queue:

- http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-php.html

You may want to check out these resources for PHP and RabbitMQ, from James Titcumb (aka "asgrim")

- https://nomadphp.com/rabbitmq-can/
- https://github.com/asgrim/rmq-slides
- http://www.slideshare.net/asgrim1/practical-message-queuing-using-rabbitmq-phpem-3rd-july-2014

and some of my own books, plus one on PHP and RabbitMQ

- https://leanpub.com/b/rmq-layout-and-patterns-for-php

Comment: 1 worker or more doesn't matter so much. the basic pattern you're using is the worker pattern. it allows you to scale as needed, but does not require you to have multiple worker instances. i recommend this approach because it allows you to grow if you need to. a simpler approach, such as the very first tutorial, may get the job done but will quickly run into limitations as you move forward.

Comment: Oh okay !! Now it's logical to use the worker pattern! Thank you very much!